# CSS: Horizontally scrolling image inside variable width div?

Tags: css, html

I have...

```
<div id="tabs">
  <!-- ... -->
  <div id="interior-photo">
    <img src="...">
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

... and ...

```
#interior-photo { overflow-x: auto; }
```

Basically, I have a page broken down into a main section and a fixed-width right sidebar. Within the main section, I have my tabbed div. The entire page grows with the width of the window, so when the window is resized, the tabbed div grows horizontally in size too.

My problem is that the image that I'm loading inside one of the tabbed divs is generally much, much wider than the window usually is (they're panorama pictures; very lengthy horizontally, but not much vertically).

I know that I can force the contents of `#interior-photo` to scroll horizontally using the CSS rule above, but that only seems to work when that same div has a **fixed width**. Since I want that div to have a **variable width**, it always seems to display the full width of the image, pushing my layout way out of whack.

I know how to fix this using Javascript, but I was wondering if anyone has a CSS-only solution. If you need more information about my layout to solve this issue, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Is it okay if the scroll bar is always showing? Did you try "overflow-x: scroll"

Comment: I'd prefer if the scrollbar was not always showing. Anyways, this doesn't work either; the image is still at full width (non-restricted). Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your target div is constrained either by a fixed width style *or* by a container with a fixed width or whose ancestors include a fixed width, you won't be able to get your target div to acquire scrollbars. It will just go as wide as its contents, and the browser scrollbars will take over.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer. There's no other way around that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way around this. You can specify to display the image with scrollbars, and thus confine the viewable portion to the size of the `div`. Basically, the image will expand to the size of the `div`, and then have a horizontal scrollbar if the horizontal image size exceeds the horizontal size of the `div`. Scrollbars will not be displayed if the image's vertical component exceeds the `div`'s. You can set both the x and y to scroll on overflow with the `overflow` declaration. However, in order to use any of these, the `div`'s size must be controlled through some means, even through the initial declaration.

```
#interior-photo { overflow-x: scroll; }
```